# R package containing C++ library cannot build for window

Tags: c++, dll, rcpp, r-package

I am trying to write a R package using Rcpp. I was successful in making it work for Linux but not for Windows.

It contains my C++ codes as well as another library.
The code is available here: https://github.com/Healthcast/TransEnt/tree/devel-win

In the `Makevars.win` you can see I run the `MakefileWin` for the library:

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -Iann_1.1.2/include -I$(BOOSTLIB)
PKG_LIBS = -Lann_1.1.2/lib -lANN -lstdc++ 
OBJECTS= RcppExports.o compute_TE.o
all: before $(SHLIB)
before: annLib
annLib:
    (cd ann_1.1.2/src; make -f MakefileWin; make clean)
```

And for making the DLL in `MakefileWin`, I'm using:

```
ANNLIB = libANN.dll
LIBNAME = ANN
DLLFLAGS = -shared 
(other stuff)
$(LIBDIR)/$(ANNLIB): $(OBJECTS)
$(C++) $(DLLFLAGS) -o cyg${LIBNAME}.dll \
    -Wl,--out-implib=lib${LIBNAME}.dll.a \
    -Wl,--export-all-symbols \
    -Wl,--enable-auto-import \
    -Wl,--whole-archive $(OBJECTS) \
    -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

The problem is I cannot make the DLL. I am getting warnings and errors. (But not in Linux) such as:

> ANN.cpp:46:9: warning: 'ANNdist annDist(int, ANNpoint, ANNpoint)' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
>
> perf.cpp:71:14: error: function 'void annResetStats(int)' definition is marked dllimport

I tried different things, but I have a problem understanding what exactly should I do here.

I also tried just copying all the source files into the src folder and have a simple makewars file, and then I got different errors such as:

> compute_TE.o:compute_TE.cpp:(.text+0x8ad): undefined reference to `_imp___Z11annAllocPtsii'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear enough. In your [code](https://github.com/Healthcast/TransEnt/blob/master/src/ann_1.1.2/include/ANN/ANNperf.h#L215)

```
DLL_API void annResetStats(int data_size);
```

And in the [code](https://github.com/Healthcast/TransEnt/blob/master/src/ann_1.1.2/include/ANN/ANN.h#L76-L80)

```
#ifdef DLL_EXPORTS
    #define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

You define `DLL_API` to make visual studio compiler happy, but R doesn't use it.

Please try to remove such lines and compile it again.

Comment: Thanks very much. That part was not my code, as a result I had no idea what are those for.

Comment: @Ghazale `DLL_API` is only useful for visual studio. Removing `DLL_API` should make your code work on Windows.